# Updating Form1's widgets by clicking Form2's button in Visual C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm fairly new to Visual C# and I'm writing an GUI app with multiple forms. One form is main window, and the rest are some kind of option windows. When showing an option window, I need to load some data to it (for example a string to window's editbox), then edit it and return back to main window when closing option window. Is there any simple way I can achieve it? 
I've found some solutions [like](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/55555/Pass-value-between-forms-using-events), or [c# event handling between two forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192561/c-sharp-event-handling-between-two-forms), but I can't really conform it to my needs. I was thinking about passing data in constructor, but how to get it back? I've found something about ShowDialog, but as I said I'm new to C# (started yesterday ^^) and don't know if I can use it.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: What you have got so far? Show us some code.

Comment: Sounds like you've found all of the tools that you need to solve your problem.  Now you just need to actually apply them.

Comment: If the user shouldn't be able to return to the main form until the option form is closed then ShowDialog() is the most straight forward method.  Just create a Public member/property on the option form to retrieve the value when it's closed (or changed the Modifiers() property of the control to Public so it can be accessed outside the form).

Answer (score 1):

I found the following previous answer which outlines sending specific properties from the one form to another:

[Send values from one form to another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form-in-c-sharp-winforms-application)

The *using* keyword will also ensure that the form is cleaned-up properly, here's a link to it's *usage* (pardon the pun...) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh598w02.aspx

I've run into the same issue to be honest, and I have to say that prior to this discussion I would just pass the parent form itself to the child and alter it in that way. Such as:

```
ChildForm child = new ChildForm(this);  //from the parent
```

and

```
public ChildForm(ParentForm parent)
{
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

Probably not the best convention though, as you probably don't need to access that much from the parent as the child.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I think I finally get it. Idle_Mind, your idea was the easiest in my point of view, so I decided to use it. If someone else has a problem like this, here's what I've coded:

In main window form: when button is clicked, a new form appears; after closing it, label1 shows the text typed in that form

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadDataForm loaddata = new LoadDataForm("initial value");
        if (loaddata.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            label1.Text = loaddata.textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

In load data form: argument passed in form's constructor appears in textBox1; textBox1's Modifiers property has to be modified to "public"

```
public LoadDataForm(string initvalue)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = initvalue;
    }
private void ApplyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

Regards,
mopsiok